# Register user asp.net identity model error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am creating a website using asp.net identity. I have created a data model based upon the default asp.net identity tables which is using the localdb. When I try to register a new user I get an error saying `Bitev2.Models.AspNetUserLogin: : EntityType 'AspNetUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
AspNetUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins' is based on type 'AspNetUserLogin' that has no keys defined.` However the AspNetUserLogin model is auto generated and contains no key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

AspNetUserLogin model

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Bitev2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AspNetUserLogin
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AspNetLogins table/model

[image: AspNetLogins table/model]

Comment: Is this database-first?

Comment: Ever figure this out? Having the same issue...

Comment: tried to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785392/register-user-asp-net-identity-model-error/26423637#26423637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [I said yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400251/how-use-roles-in-user-identity-in-mvc-5/26401618#26401618), Asp.Net Identity is something different!

> I have created a data model based upon the default asp.net identity tables which is using the localdb.

You don't need this step to register a new User. The `AspNetUserLogin` table has an other purpose, the one consisting in saving external logins for the current user. So the user can login from Google, Facebook, etc.

To simply register a user, please drop `AspNet****` tables from your model and write this code:

```
     //GET
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterNewUser(RegisterNewUserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = userViewModel.Email,
                Email = userViewModel.Email,
                EmailConfirmed =true
            };
            var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);

            //Add User to the Roles 
               string[] selectedRoles=new string[]{"Developer","Tester","Robbot"};
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
                return View();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

To use the  `AspNetUserLogin`, You need two methods or steps:

- The First method is the one that will  request a redirect to the external login provider  `ExternalLogin` for example, and
- The Second method/step you need is the one that will save the External Login in the   `AspNetUserLogin` table. this, without having this table generated in your model. Let's call this method `ExternalLoginConfirmation`.

Need code?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
     return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
              //saving the External Login in the   `AspNetUserLogin` table
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal("local url here");
                }
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

You'll need this class to!

```
    internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

If you need more information or if you are facing issue with missing types, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400251/how-use-roles-in-user-identity-in-mvc-5/26401618#26401618)

Hope this will help you...

Kind Regards!