# How to use Roles in user identity in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I want to use asp.net useridentity in mvc 5, I do these steps:

1) create a mvc project.

2) create my own database and change the connectionstring in web.config form:
    
    
  
to:

3) I run the project and create a new user to add related table to my database.

4) I wanted to add a role to a user after registration a user like this code in accountControler:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //******************* Add Role To User  **************
                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Member"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Member");
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Member");
                //****************************************************

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

5) I add

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
```

into:

```
<system.web></system.web>
```

when I create a new user my user register well but user not add to the role, and when I do this VS Create a new database in App_Data with name "ASPNETDB.MDF".
so I found a new article that explain about Role Provider Settings in web.config and:

6) I add

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

into :

```
<system.web></system.web>
```

but when I want to register new user I found this Error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Now I think my problem is when I do step 3 it will not completely create the user identity database and stored procedure! Am I using role true for MVC 5 ? Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Usually people with low rep don't put much effort in writing their questions but man, you're a star!! Upvoted for question clarity!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write

```
 !Roles.RoleExists("Member")
```

you are not using ASP.NET Identity! instead, you should use `ApplicationRole` so it extends the `IdentityRole` class

In addition, you don't need to tell the `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` in your config file. Asp.Net Identity is something different. In Asp.Net Identity there is a class named `ApplicationRoleManager` in the App_Start folder.

You should not use Asp.Net Identity as if it was the old simple membership.

Alternatively, check the beta(which means things may change) version of Identity to learn more on how to do in Identity.

Here is how to start :

- Create a new project : Choose Empty template (Not MVC not WebForm)
- Install the Asp.Net identity sample via nuget

  ```
  PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
  ```
- edit namespace to match your old project namespace
- If you want to copy some folders from your old project to the new project, copy your (Controllers, Views,... ) not the config files.

Here you can create roles as follows:

```
            var role = new IdentityRole("roleName");
            var roleresult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
```

and to create and add a user to specific roles you will use this

```
           var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "tresorunikin",
                Email = "tresorunikin@bellashada.com",
                EmailConfirmed =true
            };

            var userResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "123@Strong.Password");
            if(userResult.Succeeded){
            string[] roles =new string[]{"admin","seller","other"};
           var roleResult = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, roles);
            if(roleResult.Succeeded){
                //Here, user has been added to roles
             }
           }
```

All these are done for you by `Pranav Rastogi`, one of the Identity team at Microsoft.

Note that with these samples you target a new (beta) version of System.Web.Mvc that is newer than System.Web.Mvc 5.0.0.0 If I remember well the beta version is System.Web.MVC 5.0.1.2 or something like that

To Learn More about Identity  [click here](http://www.asp.net/identity)

**UPDATES** 
The Version in the samples is: System.Web.Mvc 5.2.1.0

Comment: FYI MVC 5.2.0 has been in release for a while now